# How can I copy rows from one Excel sheet to another and create duplicates using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook with two sheets: sheet1 has a large table of data in columns A to R, headers at row 1. Sheet2 has data in columns A to AO.

Using VBA I am trying to copy rows from sheet1 and paste them to the end of sheet2. Also I need to copy only columns A to R, not the entire row.

In other words, cells A2:R2 from sheet1 need to be copied to first AND second row that don't have data in column A.

I have the following code that copies the required cells from sheet1, but I cannot figure out how to copy every row twice:

```vb
Sub example()
    For Each ce In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        If Not IsEmpty(ce) Then
            Sheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 18).Value = Range(ce, ce.Offset(0, 17)).Value
        End If
    Next ce
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyRows()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim ws1LR As Long, ws2LR As Long

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    ws1LR = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws2LR = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    i = 2
    k = ws2LR
    Do Until i = ws1LR
        With ws1
            .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 18)).Copy
        End With

        With ws2
            .Cells(k, 1).PasteSpecial
            .Cells(k, 1).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
        End With

        k = k + 2
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Change `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` if they are called different things in your workbook.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Seems to be running perfectly except for the fact that it does not copy the last data row in sheet1. Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Add `+1` to the end of the `ws1LR = ... ` line same as the `ws2LR` line. I have edited my post, please upvote and/or accept if the answer is useful to you :)

Comment: Dangerous to use an integer to store row numbers, as they can overflow. Use long instead.