# Copy an entire row from 1 worksheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I had some code sent below but cant get it to work.

```
Sub mybus()
    Dim x As Long

    x = 2

    'start the loop
    Do While Cells(x, 1) <> ""
        'look for data with "bus"
        If Cells(x, 1).Value = "bus" Then
            'copy the entire row if it contains bus
            Workbooks("book1").Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(x).Copy
            'Go to sheet 2 activate it, we want the data here
            Workbooks("book1").Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
            'Find the first empty row in sheet2
            erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            'paste the data here
            ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("sheet2").Rows(erow)
        End If
        'go to sheet1 again and activate it
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        x = x + 1

    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't copy/paste but to answer, you need `Destination:=Worksheets("sheet2").Rows(erow+1)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy rows from one excel sheet to another and create duplicates using VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837297/how-to-copy-rows-from-one-excel-sheet-to-another-and-create-duplicates-using-vba)

Comment: @findwindow - `erow` is already sequenced to a new blank row with the [Range.Offset property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx).

Comment: You know @Jeeped, not everyone is a codewarrior like you who can read code UNFORMATTED as it was like you can =P Btw, tangent, but wanna do me a favor and solve [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012834/delete-excel-file) for me please?

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using [Range .Activate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221681(v=office.11).aspx) and [Worksheet.Activate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838003.aspx) altogether. You only need to specify the first cell in a multi-cell paste.

```
Sub mybus()
    Dim x As Long, erow As Long

    x = 2

    With Workbooks("book1").Worksheets("Sheet2")
        erow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    End With

    With Workbooks("book1").Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Do While Cells(x, 1) <> ""
            'look for data with "bus"
            If Cells(x, 1).Value = "bus" Then
                'copy the entire row if it contains bus to Sheet2's erow
                .Rows(x).Copy _
                   Destination:=.Parent.Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(erow, 1)
                'sequence erow to a new blank row
                erow = erow + 1
            End If
            x = x + 1
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.

Comment: I was close =P I knew it had to do with incrementing erow. Edit: I am surprised you kept copy/paste. Why not just set row to row? Isn't that faster?

Comment: You never know when bringing along formatting is essential and .Value transfer won't do that. If an OP uses copy, then I stick with it; if it is a Copy, Paste Special, Values then I move to value transfer.

Comment: Teach me to be like you~

Comment: Lately, I've been playing around with `erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2).Row` which seems to give consistent results in getting the next blank row. Make the code a little shorter but you will probably have to explain it a hundred times in a hundred questions.

Comment: Can you explain it to me =P I get it until (2).row. Before that, you get the last row so what's the 2 doing?

Comment: Well `B2:C3` has 4 cells right? What happens if you ask for a cell index that is larger than 4? Try this - `Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To 10: Debug.Print Range("B2:C3")(i).Address(0, 0): Next i`.

Comment: You go over but still can't tell what 2 is doing. Edit: I don't know what second index of a cell means XD

Comment: The `Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)` is a single cell. The `(2)` is saying the next cell which happens to be the one directly below it. The `.Row` is the row number of that cell. And that is why I don't use it in code posted here because it requires too much of an explanation.

Comment: Ahh see, to me, it makes more logical sense to be (1) like x=x+1 but I guess with index, 1 is itself XD

Comment: Hmm when do you use an index? I mean, how is using second index superior than +1? If you're worried about explaining, +1 makes far more sense =P

Comment: Actually to me, the more verbose `.Offset(1, 0)` makes more sense but it is all a matter of programming preferences. I try to use `vbNullString` instead of `""` even though it takes more typing. Some say that `vbNullString` is faster but if that minute amount of speed is important then why are you in VBA to begin with?

Comment: Oh ok. So it's more just how people think XD Thanks!

Comment: Well, you can't C++ in Excel XD